# Pycharm Graph window Setup

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to setup `pycharm` so that when plot is called, the graph does not pop up, rather show on a side window, if not, show within the terminal?

On the other hand, I realized there is something called "Scientific mode", but can't seem to find it under setting or view tab. Do I have to install something to get it?

Thank you, apologizes, new to `pycharm` and not familiar with it.